# Should an object query its owner?

Tags: python, object

I have a `World`

```
class World:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 10
        self.n_busStops = 10

        self.busStopMatrix = SpatialGraph(self.size, self.n_busStops, 1.0)
        self.buses = [Bus([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])]
```

Now each of the buses are going to move around the world, dropping off and picking up passengers.

The bus contains information about its route. When it gets to its next stop, it needs to query the `busStopMatrix` to find out how many passengers there are there, and how far away the next stop on its route is.

Is it a good idea for an object to query its parent like this? If so, what is this design pattern called?

Something like:

```
class World:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 10
        self.n_busStops = 10

        self.busStopMatrix = SpatialGraph(self.size, self.n_busStops, 1.0)
        self.buses = [Bus([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], owner =self)]

class Bus:
    def __init__(self, route, parent):
        self.route = route
        self.currentStop = route[0]
        self.parent = parent
    def move(self): 
        ifAtDestination():
            pickUpPassengers(self.parent.getPassengersAtStop(currentStop))
```

I otherwise can't think how the `Bus` can get information about the world it is in. The alternative I can think of is that the route is made up of references directly to the BusStops, so it can directly query them.

eg.

```
class World:
    def __init__(self):
        self.size = 10
        self.n_busStops = 10

        self.busStopMatrix = SpatialGraph(self.size, self.n_busStops, 1.0)
        self.buses = [Bus([busStopmatrix.getAllStops()])]

class Bus:
    def __init__(self, route):
        self.route = route
        self.currentStop = route[0]

    def move(self): 
        ifAtDestination():
            pickUpPassengers(currentBusStop)
```

Comment: The computation of `busStopMatrix` in the first code example seems pointless, as it not stored in the `World` instance.

Comment: @JonathanEunice Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You have one quite elegant way to do it also which consists in providing your `Bus` class with a function in the constructor to retrieve the passengers:

```
class World:
def __init__(self):
    self.size = 10
    self.n_busStops = 10

    busStopMatrix = SpatialGraph(self.size, self.n_busStops, 1.0)
    self.buses = [Bus([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], owner = self.getPassengersAtStop)]

class Bus:
    def __init__(self, route, passenger_function):
        self.route = route
        self.currentStop = route[0]
        self.passenger_function = passenger_function
    def move(self): 
        ifAtDestination():
            pickUpPassengers(self.passenger_function(currentStop))
```

This way, you don't really depend on the name of a function or whatever and Bus is unaware of the `World` class.